# i get this error java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to add the sum of certin record sets as:

> item.setText(5,String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(rs1.getString("prn_amount")+
>   Double.valueOf(rs1.getString("prv_prn")
>   + Double.valueOf(rs1.getString("adv_prn"))))));**

i get the error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException:
>   multiple points**

why is this happened could any body please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How bout splitting that all up and printing out those 3 field values....

Answer (score 0):

There are several places where you missed some braces, namely after each `getString` you only close the corresponding argument for `getString` but not for the `Double.valueOf` associated with.